# Loop through an array of threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am going to be straight up and say that this is a homework assignment. I am very close but there is one small thing I cannot figure out. The program asks the user to enter any amount of numbers in one line. For each number they enter, it will create a new thread to then print out the process of finding the Collatz conjecture for that number.

I have everything working except for the fact that I cannot create multiple threads using a for loop. I make an array of threads and then try to create a new one for each number from the input, but it seems to only make one thread and then exit the program.

Any ideas for why it isn't working?

P.S. C is definitely not my strong suit, this is only like the third program I've written in it. So I'm still learning and struggling with the language.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void *updater(int num);

int main () {
    pid_t pid;
    char input[50];
    int nums[100], size = 0, j;
    char *pch;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Enter any number(s) or 'q' to quit: ");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

        while (strcmp(input, "q") != 1) {
            pch = strtok(input, " ");

            while (pch != NULL) {
                nums[size] = atoi(pch);
                size++;
                pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

            pthread_t tid_array[size];
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);

            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                pthread_create(&tid_array[j], &attr, updater(nums[j]), NULL);
                pthread_join(&tid_array[j], NULL);
            }

            size = 0;

            printf("Enter any number(s) or 'q' to quit: ");
            fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        }
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *updater(int num) {
    printf("%d ", num);

    while (num != 1) {
        if (num <= 0) {
            printf("You cannot enter a negative number or 0\n");
            return;
        } else if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num = num / 2;
        } else {
            num = 3 * num + 1;
        }

        printf("%d ", num);
    }

    printf("\n");
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `pthread_exit(0)` in `void *updater(int num)` as it will terminate your program. You need only return `NULL` from this method.

Wait until you have created all of your threads before you join them. Joining a thread will wait for it to complete, so joining threads as soon as you create them gives you no benefit at all. This should look like:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
  pthread_create(&tid_array[j], &attr, updater(nums[j]), NULL);
}

for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
  pthread_join(&tid_array[j], NULL);
}
```

Comment: This works, but now once it goes through and prints out each number, it doesn't get to the point where the user can choose to enter more numbers or quit. It prints out that second prompt but then exits after.

Answer (score 1):

```
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            pthread_create(&tid_array[j], &attr, updater(nums[j]), NULL);
            pthread_join(&tid_array[j], NULL);
        }
```

Joining a thread waits for it to complete, so you're only running one thread at a time. Instead, create all the threads first. Then join them all when you want to wait for them all to finish (or detach them if you don't).